# Can't use paramiko to echo output from python

Tags: php, python, macos, paramiko

I have a `PHP` script which does the following

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("python test.py");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

I have a `Python` script (test.py) which does the following

```
import paramiko

myIP = "172.17.54.52"
user =  "cisco"
password =  "cisco"


def VPN_ASR9000_DN_show_testSSH(myIp,user,password) :

    HOST = str(myIp)
    hostname = HOST
    password = str(password)
    command = "sh ip int brief\n"

    username = str(user)
    port = 22

    try:
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy)

        client.connect(hostname, port=port, username=username, password=password)
        i = 0
        txt = [""] * 200
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
        for i in range(200):  # write commmand
            txt[i] = str(stdout.readline())
            if txt[i] == "":
                break

            print(txt[i])
            i += 1



    finally:
        client.close()
        print("command end")

VPN_ASR9000_DN_show_testSSH(myIP,user,password)
```

when I run this script on my `MacOS Terminal` use

```
python test.py
```

it works.

But when I run the `PHP` script on my `MacOS` it does't work

But when I run this script on my friend's `PC(linux)` it work

I have already installed `paramiko` but I don't know how my friend's PC can run it?

Comment: It could be that `shell_exec` doesn't have the `python` binary available. You can debug this as you would on a unix shell by checking `shell_exec('which python')` for example, and ensure that it returns the same interpreter as on your local machine's shell

Comment: thank you for answer I can use shell_exec for another function (for example Telnet) it's work but when I import Paramiko in test.py it doesn't work

Comment: It cannot help others help you if you just say "it does not work".